# How to pass variable into react toastify?

Tags: reactjs, toastr

So, How to pass a variable inside toaster
for example

```
var msg= 'Hello World.<br/>This is awesome.<br/>Be Happy';
```

i passed this msg varible into toastr like this...

```
toast.error(<div>msg<div>)
```

the toaster is showing "msg" not "Hello World.This is awesome.Be Happy".
someone give the right solution pls

Answer (score 4):

You are passing variable wrong :

```
toast.error(<div>msg<div>) to 
toast.error(<div>{msg}<div>) //add template literal

//Better would create component as it would print dom as a string : 
//Better approach : 
const Msg = () => {
  return (
    <>
      Hello World.
      <br />
      This is awesome.
      <br />
      Be Happy
    </>
  );
};


toast.error(<Msg/>);
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `toast.error(<div>msg<div>)` you are sending a div with `msg` as content.

If you want to show the `value` of your `msg` variable you need to use `toast.error(<div>{msg}<div>)`

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the msg variable in curly braces like so
    toast.error({msg})

Answer (score 1):

Hi Thank you all for the correction, that is correct, and  actually i am still getting the error while binding the dynamic parts.like this..

```
  var Msg='';
            Object.keys(errorsList).map((key) => {
                Msg= Msg + errorsList[key] + '<br/>';
            });

 toast.error(<div>{Msg}</div>);
```

When i bind as you said, `new line <br/>` is not working properly.please give the solution...